# How put title in table

Tags: tables

I want put a title in table, my current table is y the correction is:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{ociamthesis}  
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[H]
            \begin{center}
                \copyrightbox[b]{\begin{tabular}{|p{25mm}|c|c|c|c|c|}

\hline
\multirow{2}{=}{$\nu$SVM} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Margen C} & %
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Gamma}\\
\cline{2-5}
 & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{1e-1} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{1e-2}  \\

\hline
\multirow{2}{=}{OC-SVM} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Margen C} & %
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Gamma}\\
\cline{2-5}
 & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{1e-1} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{1e-2}  \\

\hline
\multirow{2}{=}{RNA} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Lr} & %
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{error}\\
\cline{2-5}
 & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{0.9} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{0.0001}  \\
\hline
% etc. ...

\end{tabular}   
}

            \end{center}
        \end{table} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: please add in preamble packages which are needed to test your document example (mwe: minimal working example).

Comment: @Zarko just lack this \usepackage{multirow} i edited my question

Comment: not sufficient, there are still missing packages. or they are called with your `\documentclass...` . since it is not public, i cant test your *mwe* with it. so please make *mwe* such that we can test it.

Comment: @Zarko 
I do not know about latex and I did not know what dependence was missing, apologies

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the following MWE, I have added the `copyright` package in order to be able to use the `\copyrightbox` command. I have also removed the `[H]` option from `table` (Be careful with that!). Additionally, I have removed 2 columns as you specified 5 but only need 3. According to that, I have removed all the unnecessary `\multicolumn` commands, changed the arguments of `\cline` and added the requested line. Lastly, I have removed the `center` environment and replaced it with `\centering` as the former adds additional vertical white space.

I used the `ociamthesis.cls` available [here](https://www.maths.ox.ac.uk/members/it/faqs/latex/thesis-class).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{ociamthesis}  
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{copyrightbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \centering
    \copyrightbox[b]{
      \begin{tabular}{|p{25mm}|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        technique & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{aaaaa}\\
        \hline
        \multirow{2}{=}{$\nu$SVM} & Margen C &  Gamma\\
        \cline{2-3}
         & 1e-1 & 1e-2  \\
        \hline
        \multirow{2}{=}{OC-SVM} & Margen C & Gamma\\
        \cline{2-3}
         & 1e-1 & 1e-2  \\
        \hline
        \multirow{2}{=}{RNA} & Lr & error\\
        \cline{2-3}
         & 0.9 & 0.0001  \\
        \hline
% etc. ...
      \end{tabular}   
    }{copyright info text}
\end{table} 
\end{document}
```

[image]